# is my car battery bad?

Tags: battery, buick

At 6am this morning the car battery was dead. (It snowed all night and temperature was 3 degrees this morning.) 3 hours later I went to check it out and it started right up so I let it run for 20 minutes.  Now 3 hours later the battery is dead again. Everything is shut off!  So is my battery bad or is it something else?

Comment: How old is your battery?  Are you having any other problems?  Headlights dimming at a stop, for instance?

Comment: When it didn't start did you have lights, clicks or slow turning?

Answer (score 2):

First I'd clean your battery terminals, since even a cold battery at fullish charge will try to start. After cleaning, make sure they're clamped tight and there's no corrosion.

Also, describe "won't start" - clicks, nothing, slow turnover, turns and stops, etc.